# Installing Ubuntu Kubernates 1.20 on localhost -> Documentation lead to error -> Waiting for 3 kube-system pods to start

Tags: juju, localhost, lxd, kubernetes

I was created fresh Ubuntu 20.03 on VirtualBox than started installation using documentation. Machine have Quadro RTX Card (maybe it impacts?).

Documentation is messy because there is many ways to do - whatever I checked almost all ways and results are very bad because it was never lead to success. Can you help with this installation or maybe Ubuntu Kubernetes not works and it is waste of time?

Is it extra logs is need?

Invalid documentation leading to this errors:

1. https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/install#multi-node
2. https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/install-manual
3. https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/install-local

First of all I try:

```
sudo snap install lxd

sudo lxd init
# all default apart:
# dir
# ipv6 none

sudo snap install juju --classic
juju bootstrap localhost

juju add-model k8s
juju deploy charmed-kubernetes
```

Result is 10 machines and not working masters :)

```
kubernetes-master/0*      waiting   idle   5        10.184.167.240  6443/tcp        Waiting for 3 kube-system pods to start
  containerd/2            active    idle            10.184.167.240                  Container runtime available
  flannel/2               active    idle            10.184.167.240                  Flannel subnet 10.1.1.1/24
kubernetes-master/1       waiting   idle   6        10.184.167.89   6443/tcp        Waiting for 3 kube-system pods to start
  containerd/3            active    idle            10.184.167.89                   Container runtime available
  flannel/3               active    idle            10.184.167.89                   Flannel subnet 10.1.43.1/24
```

Full status is:

```
juju status --color
Model           Controller           Cloud/Region         Version  SLA          Timestamp
k8s-production  localhost-localhost  localhost/localhost  2.8.9    unsupported  17:00:24+01:00

App                    Version  Status   Scale  Charm                  Store       Rev  OS      Notes
containerd             1.3.3    active       5  containerd             jujucharms  102  ubuntu  
easyrsa                3.0.1    active       1  easyrsa                jujucharms  345  ubuntu  
etcd                   3.4.5    active       3  etcd                   jujucharms  553  ubuntu  
flannel                0.11.0   active       5  flannel                jujucharms  518  ubuntu  
kubeapi-load-balancer  1.18.0   active       1  kubeapi-load-balancer  jujucharms  757  ubuntu  exposed
kubernetes-master      1.20.4   waiting      2  kubernetes-master      jujucharms  955  ubuntu  
kubernetes-worker      1.20.4   active       3  kubernetes-worker      jujucharms  726  ubuntu  exposed

Unit                      Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports           Message
easyrsa/0*                active    idle   0        10.184.167.48                   Certificate Authority connected.
etcd/0*                   active    idle   1        10.184.167.23   2379/tcp        Healthy with 3 known peers
etcd/1                    active    idle   2        10.184.167.180  2379/tcp        Healthy with 3 known peers
etcd/2                    active    idle   3        10.184.167.194  2379/tcp        Healthy with 3 known peers
kubeapi-load-balancer/0*  active    idle   4        10.184.167.106  443/tcp         Loadbalancer ready.
kubernetes-master/0*      waiting   idle   5        10.184.167.240  6443/tcp        Waiting for 3 kube-system pods to start
  containerd/2            active    idle            10.184.167.240                  Container runtime available
  flannel/2               active    idle            10.184.167.240                  Flannel subnet 10.1.1.1/24
kubernetes-master/1       waiting   idle   6        10.184.167.89   6443/tcp        Waiting for 3 kube-system pods to start
  containerd/3            active    idle            10.184.167.89                   Container runtime available
  flannel/3               active    idle            10.184.167.89                   Flannel subnet 10.1.43.1/24
kubernetes-worker/0*      active    idle   7        10.184.167.52   80/tcp,443/tcp  Kubernetes worker running.
  containerd/0*           active    idle            10.184.167.52                   Container runtime available
  flannel/0*              active    idle            10.184.167.52                   Flannel subnet 10.1.20.1/24
kubernetes-worker/1       active    idle   8        10.184.167.226  80/tcp,443/tcp  Kubernetes worker running.
  containerd/4            active    idle            10.184.167.226                  Container runtime available
  flannel/4               active    idle            10.184.167.226                  Flannel subnet 10.1.6.1/24
kubernetes-worker/2       active    idle   9        10.184.167.158  80/tcp,443/tcp  Kubernetes worker running.
  containerd/1            active    idle            10.184.167.158                  Container runtime available
  flannel/1               active    idle            10.184.167.158                  Flannel subnet 10.1.12.1/24

Machine  State    DNS             Inst id        Series  AZ  Message
0        started  10.184.167.48   juju-c4f295-0  focal       Running
1        started  10.184.167.23   juju-c4f295-1  focal       Running
2        started  10.184.167.180  juju-c4f295-2  focal       Running
3        started  10.184.167.194  juju-c4f295-3  focal       Running
4        started  10.184.167.106  juju-c4f295-4  focal       Running
5        started  10.184.167.240  juju-c4f295-5  focal       Running
6        started  10.184.167.89   juju-c4f295-6  focal       Running
7        started  10.184.167.52   juju-c4f295-7  focal       Running
8        started  10.184.167.226  juju-c4f295-8  focal       Running
9        started  10.184.167.158  juju-c4f295-9  focal       Running
```

Same with other sequencing from documentation all lead to nothing. Maybe I am doing something wrong maybe Ubuntu Kubernetes just not works on localhost.

```
juju add-model k8s-production
juju deploy cs:bundle/charmed-kubernetes-596
```

Even this small deployment not works (installation never ends).

```
juju add-model k8s-development
juju deploy cs:bundle/kubernetes-core-1200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks this is workaround:

```
juju config kubernetes-worker kubelet-extra-config='{protectKernelDefaults: false}'
```

https://bugs.launchpad.net/charmed-kubernetes-bundles/+bug/1918160

Comment: this is already applied for me